# Adding extensions to GeoServer using Docker

Tags: geoserver, docker

I am trying to add extensions to GeoServer running in a Docker container.

The documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/installation/docker.html is suggesting this way

```
docker run --env INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true --env STABLE_EXTENSIONS="css,monitor,pyramid" --name gs -p 8080:8080 geosolutionsit/geoserver
```

However the log is telling me `no plugin urls passed, exiting`

The documentation under the official docker image https://github.com/geosolutions-it/docker-geoserver is suggesting adding them with dynamic links sources from `

```
docker run --env PLUGIN_DYNAMIC_URLS="http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.19.1/extensions/geoserver-2.19.1-control-flow-plugin.zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.19.1/extensions/geoserver-2.19.1-libjpeg-turbo-plugin.zip" 
--rm --name gs -p 8080:8080 geoserver:test-2.19.1
```

This command exit with `"docker run" requires at least 1 argument."` I am quite new to Docker so I struggle to see what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to try another image.

```
docker run -it --env INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true --env STABLE_EXTENSIONS="css,monitor,pyramid" --name gs -p 8080:8080 docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.19.7
```

If you use a docker-compose.yml file to run Geoserver Docker, that parameters could be inserted for environment, like this:

```
  geoserver:
    image: docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.19.7
    # build: ./docker/geoserver/
    container_name: geoserver4app
    environment:
      INSTALL_EXTENSIONS: "true"
      STABLE_EXTENSIONS: "css,monitor,pyramid"
      COMMUNITY_EXTENSIONS: "backup-restore"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
```

A list for STABLE or COMMUNITY Extensions can be found on documentation: [Geoserver Docker](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/installation/docker.html)